# Many-to-many relationship troubles

Tags: linq, entity-framework, code-first, eager-loading

I am hoping to get some help. I have a code first solution, with two classes Styles and QuantityBreaks. They have a many-to-many relationship which I believe I have correct in their class definitions listed below. I seed the database with some data to both tables, the many-to-many table is created but there's no data in it as I'm not sure how to add data to it yet. I can do it manually but that gets erased when I build.

So I guess my first question is how do I seed the many-to-many table?

The second question is how do I query the QuantityBreaks table where the StyleID is say 1. I can't do a join as there isn't a foreign key in either table or do I have to do a join on the three tables? I did try using the .include statement but found that very frustrating and couldn't get that to work. I thought this should be rather simple.

QuantityBreak Class with virtual ICollection to Style:

```
public class QuantityBreak
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int QuantityBreakID { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Press Type")]
    public PressType PressType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    public double? Quantity { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Style> Styles { get; set; }
}
```

Style Class with virtual ICollection to QuantityBreaks:

```
public class Style
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int StyleID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(60), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string StyleName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(6), Display(Name = "Short Code (6)")]
    public string StyleCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Style Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Width")]
    public int ImageWidth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Height")]
    public int ImageHeight { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public int SizeID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Size Size { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuantityBreak> QuantityBreaks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FinishConstraint> FinishConstraints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please help any further?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I seed the many-to-many table?

In a many-to-many association you have to add items to a collection member, as in

```
var quantityBreak = db.QuantityBreaks.Create();
// .. set properties.
db.QuantityBreaks.AddOrUpdate(quantityBreak);

var style = db.Styles.Create();
// .. set properties.

// Add if StyleName is new, otherwise update
db.Styles.AddOrUpdate(s => s.StyleName, style);

// Make sure quantityBreak is attached 
// (AddOrUpdate does not attach exising entities)
if (db.Entry(quantityBreak).State != EntityState.Added)
    quantityBreak = db.QuantityBreaks.Find(quantityBreak.QuantityBreakID);

quantityBreak.Styles.Add(style)
d.SaveChanges();
```

As you see, a little trickery is necessary to make sure that `quantityBreak` entities that already exist in the database are attached to the context. Somehow, setting their state to `Unchanged` (which is the standard way to attach entities) throws a duplicate key exception, even though the entities aren't attached at that point.

> how do I query the QuantityBreaks table where the StyleID is say 1

I guess this means querying `QuantityBreak`s having at least one of their styles with StyleID == 1:

```
db.QuantityBreaks.Where(q => q.Styles.Any(s => s.StyleID == 1))
```

`db` is a context instance in these code snippets.

Comment: Thanks Gert, most helpful. Still having a few issues though. I put this code as a new method in my database initialiser class but the AddOrUpdate definition returned the following error: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<YPGOOS.Models.QuantityBreak>' does not contain a definition for 'AddOrUpdate' and no extension method 'AddOrUpdate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<YPGOOS.Models.QuantityBreak>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\YPGOOS\YPGOOS\Models\myDatabaseInitialiser.cs

Comment: It's [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or (EF6) [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176991%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Gert, added the using System.Data.Entity.Migrations; and that error went away. Now getting an error on the lambda expression on this line db.Styles.AddOrUpdate(style, s => s.StyleName); - the error is: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'YPGOOS.Models.Style' because it is not a delegate type.  What does that expression do, I notice you didn't have it on the previous version of AddOrUpdate?

Comment: I tried it without the lambda expression and got the following error on this line: db.Entry(stocks).Collection(q => q.Styles).Load();  Error:  The source query for this EntityCollection or EntityReference cannot be returned when the related object is in either an added state or a detached state and was not originally retrieved using the NoTracking merge option.

Comment: OK, first check if the `quantityBreak` is in the `Unchanged` state.

Comment: Gert, sorry I'm a real novice - can you suggest how to do that please?

Comment: Haven't got time right now, but I've noticed that there are some tricky edges here about which I even posted an issue in the EF CodePlex site. I'll get back to you.

Comment: As I suspected, there appears to be a bug in `AddOrUpdate`: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128.